# Windows Volume shadow copy error: 2155348129

Tags: windows, backup, recovery, shadow-copy, volume-shadow-service

Developing a VSS writer app:
see this error during backup, initiated by windows backup tool,
is there defined error codes for `2155348129` from Microsoft?

> The backup operation that started at '‎2010‎-‎07‎-‎20T02:54:19.354000000Z' has failed because the Volume Shadow Copy Service operation to create a shadow copy of the volumes being backed up failed with following error code '2155348129'

This does not happen when `VSSwriter` service (my application) is stopped.

Any help is appreciated. Nothing useful found on TechNet.

**Hackish workaround**:
Interestingly the back up works is when "windows partition is made active". Of course this leaves the system non-boot-able upon restart

Comment: This belongs on superuser. Not development related.

Comment: no, this is related to application development and not just system administration. There is a component called VSS writer implemented using VSS API.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite your question as "I'm developing a VSS writer component, but when I attempt to do a backup using it, I get ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TechNet Blog

Decimal [`2155348129` is `0x807800A1` in hex](https://www.google.com/search?q=2155348129+to+hex).

Quickly searching the Internet for this value takes me to this blog:

- Microsoft TechNet "filecab" blog, Jose Barreto, 2009-09-16, [*Diagnosing Failures in Windows Server Backup – Part 1 (VSS/SPP Errors)*](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2009/09/16/diagnosing-failures-in-windows-server-backup-part-1-vssspp-errors/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/BhJez).)

#### It's an HRESULT

This error code is of a special [type called an `HRESULT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT).

#### Namely it's a VSS related HRESULT

And TechNet has a table that lists our specific HRESULT value:

- TechNet: [*Troubleshoot VSS issues that occur with Windows Server Backup (WBADMIN) in Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2*](https://archive.is/q5XHW#selection-1889.0-1905.120):

  - HRESULT: `2155348129`
  - HRESULT (in hex): `0x807800A1`
  - Error Message: `A Volume Shadow Copy Service operation failed. Please check "VSS" and "SPP" application event logs for more information.`

*Note:* `VSS` is short for `Volume Shadow Copy Service`. SPP is short for `Shared Protection Point`. They log into the regular Windows `application` event log. And they use `VSS` and `SPP` as their event-`Source`-identifier.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/9cf42e8a-2a33-47c5-a797-269330e9ba1a
this has some recommendation to make windows partition active, but that makes OS not boot-able after restart. Is this a bug with Windows?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with VSS errors vs a SBS backup.

#### Wasn't low disk space in my case

Dell Pro Support (very good) discounted the issue being with the HDD configuration which is referred to all over the www.  They did say to watch out for HDDs that are very low on space causing VSS issues for Server backup but this was not the case.

#### Check VSS writer status

My Fix:
Run `vssadmin list writers` and see if they have stalled as part of the backup.  A reboot or two should set these back to normal.  Try a backup now.
Check to see if any SharePoint updates are causing the issue. Run the `SharePoint Configuration Wizard` from the start menu (Next, Next, Finish), reboot and rerun the backup.

Hope this helps someone else out there - let me know if you need any more info.

www.mtechnical.co.uk

Answer (score 3):

Sharepoint Foundation is causing the issue. By running the "Sharepoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard", it will fix the backup issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on my W Server 2008 R2.
I finaly found that a virtual server instance was running on my hyper-v server.
Apparently there is a bug that cannot handle parallellism of backups of the v-server and the real server.

I believe I read that there is a fix for this in the knowledge base:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/958184/virtual-machine-backup-operations-fail-in-windows-server-2008-when-hyper-v-virtual-machine-files-are-saved-on-a-volume-that-is-mounted-on-a-failover-cluster-by-using-a-volume-guid

When shutting down the (not important) virtual machine that was running, the issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by mtechnical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6652682/4247268) put me on the right track, sorry don't have enough rep to vote you up.

#### Cause was SharePoint VSS writer

Basically `vssadmin list writers` allowed me me to see that `SPSearch4 VSS Writer` was holding everything up with an `inconsistent shadow copy` error and a few quick Google searches later I was all good.

Hopefully that helps you get to where you need to be.

#### Underlying cause was SharePoint Service Pack

In case anyone else gets here due to backup failing with SBS 2011 even on a clean install with all patches, the cause is due to the `SharePoint Server service pack`. To resolve run the `Sharepoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard`. And after that you should be able to re-run `vssadmin list writers` and see all errors are cleared.

Cheers
Kactus

Answer (score 0):

I had a SQL server installed. With too many databases. When I deleted some databases the error went away and the backup could continue as normal.